# Particle effect like collision effect by chillingo

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

Chillingo launch a new game name "collision effect" attach is the image of the game any one know how to create this effect. i think it's collision by particles how to create this using cocos2D?

[image: Collision effect by chillingo]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By programming it yourself.

This isn't supported by the particle system in cocos2d. You need a particle system where particles can attract or deflect each other, or even a particle system where you can apply physics or other movement logic to individual particles. Cocos2d doesn't give you control over individual particles.

You could create this with sprite-batched sprites but this won't be efficient or fast. Usually such systems are implemented at the lowest level, meaning custom OpenGL drawing, perhaps optimized with shaders.